# How to get magento quote created time?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, shopping-cart, quoteitem

I'm looking for a way to get `magento` quote created time, My goal is to get the quote created time & set 10 min timer , if customer checkout while 10min other wise i'll clear the cart items. Timer will refresh back to 10 min upon each new item inserted into cart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how but in sales_flat_quote you have the created at and updated at timestamp and you can get the difference

Comment: hi am working on it .can you wait

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have found solution after some hardwork for your requirement.

Steps:1 In custom module's  config.xml  make two observers.

```
 <checkout_cart_product_add_after >
                 < observers >
                    <kinex_order >
                        <class> kinex_order/observer </class>
                         <method>catalogProduct </method >
                    </kinex_order >
                </observers >
             </checkout_cart_product_add_after >



<controller_action_predispatch >
                 < observers >
                    <kinex_order >
                        <class> kinex_order/observer </class>
                         <method>getControllerAction </method >
                    </kinex_order >
                </observers >
             </checkout_cart_product_add_after >
```

**Methods:**

```
/* This method set 10 mins after item added to quote object */

   public function catalogProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

         $quote=Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

        $removeQuoteTime=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRemoveQuoteTime();   

           $updateAt=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');             
          if($removeQuoteTime){
           $updateAt=$removeQuoteTime;
          }
          else{
           $updateAt=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
          }
         $currentDate = $updateAt;
         $removeQuoteTime=$currentDate+600;//10 mins add
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setRemoveQuoteTime($removeQuoteTime);



    }


/* below method empty cart if customer does not checkout within 10 min  */

public function  getControllerAction (Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

$currentTime =strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));      
    $removeQuoteTime=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getRemoveQuoteTime();
    //logic 

    if($currentTime < $removeQuoteTime){

    }else{
    $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();        
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        } 
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsRemoveQuoteTime();    
    }    

}
```

Comment: I'll try this & let you know, Thank you for your hard work, If its worked i'll accept it